# Firing a script on click?

Tags: php, ajax

Say I have a URL:

```
<a href="hello.html" id="4298">hello</a>
```

When someone clicks this link, I want it to fire a script off using ajax so we can track how many times this link has been clicked behind the scene.

My page is called `track.php` which will pull the ID 4298 via GET, `track.php?id=4298` and then it updates the database respectively.

How would I go about coding this in javascript/ajax so upon this link being clicked, in form of an `"onclick event"`, this track.php will be ran behind the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that to do a request in the background, you will need to wait for the AJAX response to follow the click. If that's what you want, then using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var track = function(obj) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "track.php?id="+obj.id,
    success: function(){
      window.location.href = obj.href;
    }
  });
  return false;
};
$('a').click(track);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var anchors = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, anchorsLength = anchors.length; i < anchorsLength; i++) {

   a.onclick = function(event) {

       event.preventDefault();
       var id = this.id,
           xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

       xhr.open('track.php?id=' + id);

       xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
             if(xhr.status == 200) {
                 window.location = this.href;
             }
          }
       }  
       xhr.send();  
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that `XMLHttpRequest()` doesn't support older versions of IE.

If you are using jQuery, use the library's AJAX functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    window.doTheThing = function() {
        //send a request to your 'track.php' URL here 
    };
</script>

<a href="hello.html" id="4298" onclick="doTheThing(); return false;">hello</a>
```